# How to post inner content of div in javascript when it's clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div that contains people's names, which is coming dynamically.

I want to show related content of people, when it's clicked. For that, I need to pass name of person to javascript when div is clicked.

How can I achieve this?

**Note:** I am not using any button.

Comment: `<?php $x=0; if( have_rows('product', 'options') ):
   while ( have_rows('product', 'options') ) : the_row(); $x++; ?>
   <?php if (get_sub_field('p_category', 'options') == 'Monitors'):  ?>
   <div class="col-md-4 left_spacing col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
   <div class="col-md-12 content_modle lcd col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
   <a href="#">
   <img src="<?php the_sub_field('p_image', 'options'); ?>" class="img-responsive center-block " />
   <p class="text-center module_txt"><?php the_sub_field('p_title', 'options'); ?></p>
   </a>
                        </div>`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for example:

```
$('#parent_block_that_not_insert_dynamicly').on('click', 'div.that_add_dynamycly', function() {
var data = $(this).text(); //get name
$.ajax({
   method: "POST",
   data: data,
   url: "url.php"
})
.done(function(msg) {
  alert('saved')
});
});
```